# Impex import export Error saving batch in bulk mode ambiguous unique keys

Tags: import, export, data-migration, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

When I am exporting data from one environment and importing it to another, I am seeing an ambiguous unique keys error. I did check the ambiguity but did not find anything would cause this violation.

I get the following error (there are several identical errors but only posting 1):

```
Error Begin
```

> **insert_update ABClCMSParagraphComponent;&Item;catalogVersion(catalog(id),version)[unique=true,allownull=true];content[lang=en];creationtime[forceWrite=true,dateformat=dd.MM.yyyy
>   hh:mm:ss];modifiedtime[dateformat=dd.MM.yyyy
>   hh:mm:ss];name;owner(&Item)[allownull=true,forceWrite=true];uid[unique=true,allownull=true]
>   ABClCMSParagraphComponent,8796158592060,,,Error saving batch in bulk
>   mode [reason:
>
> unique keys {catalogVersion=CatalogVersionModel (8796093186649@41),
>   uid=DMparaleftdescrip} for model ABClCMSParagraphComponentModel
>   (8796158657596@1) - found 2 item(s) using the same keys]. Will try
>   line-by-line mode.,
>
> unique keys {catalogVersion=CatalogVersionModel (8796093186649@41),
>   uid=comp_000003UX} for model ABClCMSParagraphComponentModel
>   (8796158592060@1) - found 2 item(s) using the same keys
>   ;Item111;abcContentCatalog:Staged;"< p >Hello < a href="">world< /a><
>   /p>";12.09.2017 07:04:12;18.09.2017 09:38:39;Feed Article -
>   Makeup;;comp_000003UX

```
Error End
```

What would be the reason why it's showing the ambiguous error?

Comment: Could you share the impex here?

Comment: Here's the row I am trying to import:  
This is the generated impex from the export:
Header -> 
# &Item;catalogVersion;content_en;creationtime;modifiedtime;na‌​me;onlyOneRestrictio‌​nMustApply;owner;uid‌​;visible 

Row -> 
Item111;abcContentCatalog:Staged;"<p>Hello <a href=""exampleabc.com"">world</a></… 07:04:12;18.09.2017 09:38:39;Feed Article;true;;comp_000003UX;true

Comment: In addition, both check boxes are selected when importing: 1- Enable code execution, 2-Distributed mode

Answer (score 0):

The logs didn't show the error clearly with the 2 check boxes that were selected.  When I deleted these 2 columns, owner(&Item) & creationtime, the script imported successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Often, when no specific errors are shown, there was a error saving the item. In your case it might be the initial attributes "owner" and "creationdate". If the item is present, initial attributes cannot be changed.

Comment: Yes, that's what has happened. Thanks!